# YARN log aggregation for Spark streaming

Tags: hadoop-yarn, spark-streaming

The documentation for YARN log aggregation says that logs are aggregated after an application completes.

Does this rule out the applicability of YARN log aggregation for Spark streaming jobs because in theory streaming jobs run for a much longer duration and potentially don't ever terminate.

Thanks,
Ranjit